# Stuck with updating a column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my table `likes`

```
id  type parent country votes
1   1   0       US      0 # This value need to be 9
2   2   1       US      6
19  3   1       US      3
3   3   2       US      3
7   3   2       US      3
4   10  3       US      1
5   10  3       US      1
6   10  3       US      1
10  10  7       US      1
9   10  7       US      1
8   10  7       US      1
20  10  19      US      1
21  10  19      US      1
22  10  19      US      1
```

I'm doing a script that updates the total votes in the table.

Here, `type 10 updates type 3`, `type 3 updates 2 and 1`, `type 2 updates 1`

You'll see how it works when u run my script.

Here, `id 1` needs to be 9, and should not refresh each time the script runs. The others dont. But I cant find a way to update 1 without doubling it's value.

Can you help me find a way?

Heres the script.

```
$conn = connect();

$what = 10;
$pathType = 15;

while ( $pathType >=2 )
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("select max(type) as type from likes where type < :type and country = 'US'");
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $pathType);
$stmt->execute();
$pathData = $stmt->fetch();
$pathType = $pathData['type'];
echo 'Path Type is '.$pathType.'<br>';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("select sum(votes) as votes, parent as parent from likes where type=:type group by parent");
    $stmt->bindParam(':type', $pathData['type']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->rowCount();

        while( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) {
            echo $row['parent']." ".$row['votes'];
            echo "<br>";

            if($row['parent'] == 1){
            echo 'Passed Level 1<br>';
                $wtf = $conn->prepare("update likes set votes=votes+:votes where id=:parent");
            }else{
                $wtf = $conn->prepare("update likes set votes=:votes where id=:parent");
            }

            $wtf->bindParam(':votes', $row['votes']);
            $wtf->bindParam(':parent', $row['parent']);
            $wtf->execute();
        }
    echo "-----------------------------------------------<br>";
}
```

Here r the creates in case you need them:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Host:                         127.0.0.1
-- Server version:               5.5.25 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
-- Server OS:                    Win64
-- HeidiSQL version:             7.0.0.4053
-- Date/time:                    2013-05-17 14:41:11
-- --------------------------------------------------------

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

-- Dumping database structure for wwp-db
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `wwp-db`;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `wwp-db` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `wwp-db`;


-- Dumping structure for table wwp-db.likes
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `likes`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `parent` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `country` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `votes` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4176 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

-- Dumping data for table wwp-db.likes: 14 rows
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `likes` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `likes` (`id`, `type`, `parent`, `country`, `votes`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 0, 'US', 9),
    (2, 2, 1, 'US', 6),
    (3, 3, 2, 'US', 3),
    (4, 10, 3, 'US', 1),
    (5, 10, 3, 'US', 1),
    (6, 10, 3, 'US', 1),
    (7, 3, 2, 'US', 3),
    (8, 10, 7, 'US', 1),
    (9, 10, 7, 'US', 1),
    (10, 10, 7, 'US', 1),
    (19, 3, 1, 'US', 3),
    (20, 10, 19, 'US', 1),
    (21, 10, 19, 'US', 1),
    (22, 10, 19, 'US', 1);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `likes` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1 */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first row in likes doesn't meet the conditions of your if statement in the first instance.

```
if($row['parent'] == 1){
  echo 'Passed Level 1<br>'; //This doesn't apply to row with id 1 - but does to one with parent id 1
  $wtf = $conn->prepare("update likes set votes=votes+:votes where id=:parent");
}else{
 //Does not affect row with id 1 as it has a parent of 0
 $wtf = $conn->prepare("update likes set votes=:votes where id=:parent");
}
```

Edit: Ok so its executing this:
 and updating row 0

```
$wtf = $conn->prepare("update likes set votes=votes+:votes where id=:parent");
```

when it reaches a row with parent id 1,

You are instructing it to Add to votes not set to a value, each time you refresh it will naturally add more, if you want it to stop at a certain value add another condition to the query or code

Comment: It gets updated with the values 9. Problem here is, if u refresh the page, it'll be 15 then even more and even more.

Comment: Any idea how to do this? I've run out of ideas.

Comment: If i change that, it'll give me 6 not 9.